# Using android fragments or calling an activity?

Tags: android, android-sliding

In android when using SlidingMenu library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu is it better to use fragments for side views? or calling an activity would work when the view is swiped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The side views don't necessarily fill the entire screen and it is impossible to display multiple Activities at once. So I recommend using Fragments.